# Showing updated values on widget on Android app

Tags: android, widget

I am making widget for mobile application. Widget should update data from .JSON file from internet. I am using Android Studio. At this point my widget gets data from .JSON, but I can't figure out how to show these values on my widget.
Class FetchWeatherTaskk gets values from internet, but it is executed at the end of the method onUpdate, so the values that I want to show in widget is always null for me.

```
FetchWeatherTaskk weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTaskk();
weatherTask.execute("94043");
```

These lines calls the class and get data from internet, but it is always executed at the end of method. I don't understand why.

I know I have to use Remote views to change text in my widget. But I don't know how to get values before sending them to widget.

I am sorry for my bad English.

My widget class:

```
public class WidgetOru extends AppWidgetProvider {

String v1, v2;

public class FetchWeatherTaskk extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTaskk.class.getSimpleName();

    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr)
            throws JSONException {

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";

        final String OWM_zeno_AT_5s_C = "zeno_AT_5s_C";
        final String OWM_sws200_synop_code = "sws200_synop_code";


        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);


        // Get the JSON object representing the day
        JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(0);

        // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.

        JSONObject weatherObject;
        weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
        v1 = weatherObject.getString(OWM_zeno_AT_5s_C);
        weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
        v2 = weatherObject.getString(OWM_sws200_synop_code);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        // If there's no zip code, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                    "Link_to_.json_is_here;


            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast string: " + forecastJsonStr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // This will only happen if there was an error getting or parsing the forecast.
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
    FetchWeatherTaskk weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTaskk();
    weatherTask.execute("94043");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int widgetID = appWidgetIds[i];
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_oru);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);     //Paraso teksta is XML
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, v1);             //Pakeicia teksta i v1 kuris turetu rodyt temperatura bet nerodo
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetID, views);
    }

}}
```